# .htaccess - Redirect from trailing slash URL to non trailing slash whilst retaining www. and https rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to get my .htaccess file to redirect any URL with a trailing slash to a non-trailing slash version. E.g. example.com/contact/ to example.com/contact

I need to retain the http to https and www. non wwww. rules as per my current .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ https://%1/$1 [L,R=301,NE]

# ensure https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ https://%1/$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace all of your rule with these 3 redirect rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# ensure https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

## Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: sure the first two rules should use the L-flag? If somebody calls http://[...]/ the second rule changes to https but the trailing slash remains, right?

Comment: @JoshuaK: Thanks for spotting, it was my mistake in 2nd rule. It is corrected now.

Comment: Sry again... but: Why redirecting multiple times instead of walk through all the rules and make the redirect at the end?

Comment: sure but. rewritecond is only  valid for the next rewriterule. so after each rewriterule the other rewritecond are "forgotten"... EDIT: And why L and R together? normaly the processing is canceled when redirecting. No need for L flag when using R=301, or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes but I don't know how to combine all 3 rules into one since `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` is only applicable for 3rd rule. For a URL like `http://www.example.com/abc123/` there will be 2 redirects not 3. Try to test without `L` flag and you will see problems. btw we shouldn't prolong this comments section. If you want start a new question and we'll take it up there.

Comment: This doesn't work. It doesn't redirect from www. to non-www. it just 404 errors.

Comment: Very rule in my answer does the same i.e. `www` removal from URLs. What URL are you entering in browser and what it gets redirected to before giving 404?